# Show/hide tables using drop-down - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I've been working on this project to show/hide tables using a drop-down list and my code works fine , but due to the requirements of the CMS and ecommerce cart, I can only use `id`s on tables (rather then classes and id's).

The idea is that you can select your suburb from the dropdown menu and based on how your suburb fits within a category (i.e north, east etc.) you get shown the appropriate table.

Here's a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CHQ42/1/)

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('#billing_address2').change(function () {
        $('.calendar').hide();
        if ($(this).val() == "None") {
            $('#empty').show();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "Sandringham" || $(this).val() == "Mt Roskill") {
            $('#table2').show();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "Glen Eden" || $(this).val() == "Lynfield") {
            $('#table3').show();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "Arch Hill" || $(this).val() == "Owairaka") {
            $('#table4').show();
        }
        if ($(this).val() == "Castor Bay" || $(this).val() == "Hillcrest" || $(this).val() == "West Harbour") {
            $('#table5').show();
        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="billing_address2" name="billing_address2">
    <option selected="selected" value="None">Choose Suburb</option>
    <option value="Arch Hill">Arch Hill</option>
    <option value="Castor Bay">Castor Bay</option>
    <option value="Glen Eden">Glen Eden</option>
    <option value="Hillcrest">Hillcrest</option>
    <option value="Lynfield">Lynfield</option>
    <option value="Mt Roskill">Mt Roskill</option>
    <option value="Owairaka">Owairaka</option>
    <option value="Sandringham">Sandringham</option>
    <option value="West Harbour">West Harbour</option>
</select>
<table id="empty" class="calendar">
    <tr>
        <td>table 1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="table2" class="calendar" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>table 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="table3" class="calendar" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>table 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="table4" class="calendar" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>table 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="table5" class="calendar" style="display:none">
    <tr>
        <td>table 5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I fail to see what the problem is?

Comment: I need the code to work without classes on the tables - i can only use IDs

e.g. <table id="table2 calendar">

Comment: @EdWaldegrave Then just remove the classes and update your jQuery accordingly? Why do you need someone else to just change a couple of words around for you?

Comment: Unfortunately the limit of my jQuery knowledge has been reached. I was pretty lucky to get it this far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem is the `$('.calendar').hide()` part that is using a class, an easy solution is to call :

`$("#tableX").hide()` on each table (with X=1,2,3,4,5), or even

`$("table").hide()`, but then you would better use a div around and use `$("#yourDiv table")` to avoid hiding other tables on the page.

Comment: could you please put this into a fiddle for me?

Answer (score 1):

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CHQ42/3/   Or http://jsfiddle.net/CHQ42/5/

JS:

```
$('table').hide();
```

OR

```
    $('#empty').hide();
    $('#table2').hide();
    $('#table3').hide();
    $('#table4').hide();
    $('#table5').hide();
```